# How to update hibernate entity when DDL update to add a new column is required

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created an application using struts2 and hibernate that uploads an excel file in to the database and perform other CRUD operations.
However now a change requirement has come up where the user should be able to control the database schema from UI which means the user should have the ability to add new columns on the fly through a user interface whenever excel file has new columns inside the database.

I am not sure how can I achieve this as updating the database will still leave my entity class untouched.

To illustate the issue consider the situation:
I have ab excel file of employee with only two columns : name and roll number. So I create an entity class

```
Class Student{
    int id;
    string name;

    getters and setters
}
```

Using this entity class I can perform CRUD operations and upload excel file in to database.

Now what do I do if I need to have a new column in excel say "age" and and this "age" should also then be created inside the database. And this new column has to be added dynamically from user interface.

Is there a way to update my entity on the fly or is there any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to do something like that :

```
Class Student{
    int id;
    string name;
    List<Attribute> attributeList;

    getters and setters
}

Class Attribute {
  int id;
  String key;
  Object value;
}
```

With a oneToMany relationship between your students and the attributes you should have no issues having dynamic fields in your students.

Hope it helps!